# passenger side high beam and low beam not working new bulbs and fuse are not blown

Tags: headlight

My 2005 Honda Accord hybrid passenger side high beam and low beam not working new bulbs and fuse are not blown

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://docar.cz/navody-k-obsluze/Honda-Accord-Hybrid-Servisni-manual05.pdf) wiring diagram (hopefully for your car), the only part that is common to both high and low beams which would not affect the other side of the car, is the earth connection I have highlighted.  You need to find this connection and see where it bolts to the car body.  Check any connectors on this wire and also the bolt connection to the body.

I may have the left/right, driver/passenger side mixed up, but you get the idea.  Check the black wires to both ground connections G201 and G301.

[image]